# What is the automorphism group of Lie group $E_6$

Tags: lie-groups

I found out that there are outer automorphisms of compact Lie group $E_6$. For example complex conjugation $\tau$ as defined in [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.0431v1.pdf) Yokota paper is outer automorphism of $E_6$ which fix $F_4$ subgroup. This means that automorphism group of $E_6$ is bigger than $E_6$ (embedded into $Aut(E_6)$ as inner automorphisms divided by 3-element center $\mathbb Z_3$). Is it known what is the full automorphism group of $E_6$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a compact simply-connected semisimple Lie group $G$ the quotient group $Out(G)=Aut(G)/Inn(G)$ is isomorphic to the automorphism group of the Dynkin diagram, which is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ in case of $E_6$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics)). Now we have the exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow Inn(G) \rightarrow Aut(G) \rightarrow Out(G)\rightarrow 1,
$$
which is an extension problem. For the automorphism groups of the corresponding semisimple Lie algebras, the exact sequence splits, so that $Aut(\mathfrak{g})$ is a semidirect product of $Inn(\mathfrak{g})$ and $Out(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: Thank you ! Semidirect product by cyclic group $\mathbb Z_2$ means that in $K=Aut(G)$ there are two components of $E_6/\mathbb Z_3$. Let $K_0$, $K_1$ be these components, $1\in K_0$. Let's consider set $M$=$g\tau g^{-1}$ for $g$ in $E_6$. It is subset of $K_1$. According to Robert Bryant answer to this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249091/a-few-questions-about-e-6-and-its-symmetric-spaces question set $M$ is equal to symmetric space $E_{IV}$. Topologically both components $K_0$ and $K_1$ are the same. Can we find $E_{IV}$ in $K_0$ ? For example $M_0$=$\{\tau g:g\in M\}$ ?

Comment: I see. There is a long discussion in the comments on your MO question. Perhaps your question about $E_{IV}$ belongs then there, if it is reopened, or you pose a new question, which focuses more on this point.